# How to draw Density Plot of two groups in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I have a dataframe with few lines shown below:

```
AlleleFrequency    Region
0.0451128   intergenic
0.0451128   intergenic
0.0075188   Genic
0.0037594   intergenic
0.0263158   Genic
```

I would like to get a plot as shown below with density on Y-axis and X-axis with allele frequencies of the two groups "intergenic" and "Genic" colored differently. Could someone help?
[image]

I tried with the below function.

```
ggplot(DEL, aes(AFS_adj, fill = Genic)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5))
```

which does not give the desired output.

Comment: You asked for a density, but the plot looks like an histogram.

Comment: im confused with the same. The plot is a histogram but the Y--axis is labelled as "density".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(DEL,aes(x=AlleleFrequency,y=..density..,fill=Region))+
geom_histogram(position="dodge")+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","black"))
```

Varying the `binwidth` argument of `geom_histogram` you can make the plot look like the one you want to achieve

Comment: It gives the output in the desire way except that Y-axis has "Count" values instead of  "Density" . Would you think it could be a matter of labelling or could it be really plotted using 'density' values?